# Gate driver output 25% of PWM frequency - any idea how this is possible?

Tags: gate-driving, testing

I am testing isolated gate driver IRS10752LPBF on the bench and I have a result I don't understand.

The only change I made on my test rig compared to the typical application proposed in the datasheet is that I don't have a bootstrap for the high side but an independent isolated power supply as I want to be able to run at 100% duty factor later on.

The gate output pin is floating for these tests (no MOSFET driven).

Screen shot attached: channel 1 yellow is the PWM signal while channel 3 purple is the gate driver output pin measured against the high side reference voltage.

As it can be seen on the screenshot, the output runs at 1/4 of the input frequency.

I have never seen that before. How is it possible? I am running at relatively low frequency. Is it a possible reason? My controller is limited at 1 kHz on this rig. (I don't see why but I am clueless on this one ...)

Any insight on what could cause this will be welcome
Added a second screen shot after a suggestion was made in a comment: The first  is the original at 50% duty factor while the second is at 25%

At the request of a commenter I am adding a crude schematic of the rig. It is very simple. Channel 1 is measured between pin 3 and 2 and channel 2 ( or 3 as I changed during the tests) between pin 5 and 4
[image: schematic]
[[image: 25% duty factor][2]]
[image: 50%% duty factor]
Thanks

Comment: do you get different output when you attach a reactive load?

Comment: Is it still 25% if you change the input signal frequency? Or the duty cycle?

Comment: it remains 25% when I change frequency in the 50Hz 1kHz range. I have not thought of varying the duty factor. Going to do it now. I addeed a 10kOhm load and it did not change. also I tried 2 different chips and get the same result.

Comment: I just ran the rig at 25% df following the suggestion of DKNguyen and get a different result. Adding screen shot to the question.

Comment: Pretty weird. Can you post your current test schematic?

Comment: Where is your bootstrap diode?

Comment: @JonRB OP has replaced bootstrap mechanism with an isolated supply for 100% duty operation

Comment: as explained in my post there is no bootstrap. I have 2 isolated power supply one for the logical side and one for the output side.

Comment: You sure you can operate a bootstrap chip like this?

Comment: @JonRB Should be fine. It's mentioned in IRF app notes.

Comment: I thought of that and to the best of my knowledge it works ( it is used daily) . I swapped channels 1 and 3 and did not see a difference. The scope is a Tektronix TPS2024 with isolated channels

Comment: That is not your full test schematic. Show us how you connected the 10K load. Add decoupling caps to the rails, and try a test load of a 1nF capacitor from HO to to VS.

Comment: THis is the full current test schematic. I have initially 100nF decoupling caps between pins 1 and 2 and pin 4 and 6 and the 10k resistance was between pin 4 and 5 I removed them one by one when I saw the signal I have posted. At the moment the schematic posted is exactly what's on the breadboard

Comment: @ DKNguyen I added a 1nf cap between HO and VS. It did not change anything

Comment: I'm sort of wondering if the circuit needs some kind of connection, any connection between Vs and COM as would normally appear in such a circuit. Like through a 10K resistor or something because it's not actually a galvanically isolated IC.

Comment: I think It should not need such a connection. I have used other gate drivers in the past with similar setting and have never seen such a thing

Comment: Can this work with 2 completely isolated power supplies? Look at the blockdiagram in the datasheet. Can the low side communicate with the "HV Well" without some ground return? (Normally trough the load to shared ground)

Comment: @Unimportant That was my thought too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @ DKNguyen and @ Unimportant I found the problem. You are right: This particular chip apparently requires a connection between Vs and COM. On the rig I could short the 2 pins and the weird signals became normal.
I then put a 1 meg resistor between Vs and Com and it still worked so it can be transformed in something useful as shorting VS and Com can't really work on a high side gate driver.

Comment: Good. Don't forget to accept your own answer to indicate to the system that the problem has been solved. Otherwise it keeps popping it back onto the home page looking for an answer. You may have to wait some hours or a day before you can accept. I can't remember how long.

Comment: As @Transistor kindly mentioned, that enforced delay before self-accepting is possible, is [48 hours from the time the question was asked](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). So for this question, 2021-05-04 at 20:20:08Z is the earliest when accepting this self-answer becomes possible.